# Postgress change relationship between two tables in NestJs

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

i have table file and product, now its one to many, but i want to change realtionship to many-to-one. And i use mirgation in NestJS.
`My code`

```
import type { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class RelationshipInImageCategory1671354171023 implements MigrationInterface {

  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE file_entity DROP CONSTRAINT ' +
    'public.categories_entity.FK_23cf240bcad452131ad38135723');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE product_entity ADD CONSTRAINT ' +
    'FK.file_entity FOREIGN KEY (file_entity.id) REFERENCES file_entity (id)');
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE file_entity ADD CONSTRAINT ' +
    'public.categories_entity.FK_23cf240bcad452131ad38135723 ' +
    'FOREIGN KEY (product_entity.id) REFERENCES categories_entity (id)');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE product_entity DROP CONSTRAINT ' +
    'FK.file_entity');
  }

}
```

I have error {
query: 'ALTER TABLE file_entity DROP CONSTRAINT public.product_entity.FK_23cf240bcad452131ad38135723',
parameters: undefined,
driverError: error: syntax error at or near "."
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like work.

```
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS product_entity DROP' +
    ' CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS "FK_e2c62cb8eaec0d909de8264e5ca"');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE file_entity ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS product_id INT');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE file_entity ADD CONSTRAINT ' +
    'FK_product FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product_entity(id)');
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE product_entity ADD CONSTRAINT ' +
    'FK_e2c62cb8eaec0d909de8264e5ca FOREING KEY(ImageId) REFERENCES file_entity(id)');
    await queryRunner.query('ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS file_entity DROP CONSTRAINT ' +
    'IF EXIST "FK_categories"');
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).